# Why is the Schmidt decomposition of an operator not unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

I came across this question while reading through Treil's LADW, but couldn't come up with an answer. Why is the Schmidt decomposition of an operator not unique?